# Where are release notes of Rust crates published

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-crates

Is there a *standard* place where one can see what's new/fixed in a certain crate release? I couldn't find such a section in [crates.io](https://crates.io/) or [docs.rs](https://docs.rs/).

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing fixed in the Rust ecosystem.

There are a few fuzzy standards that more and more crate maintainers will follow, mainly the [keepachangelog](https://keepachangelog.com/en/1.0.0/) one, but there's no specific display in crates.io or docs.rs so you'll have to go to the repository.

IMO it would be a good idea to automatically add a link to files called CHANGELOG.md or releases.md in those reference sites.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no standard place for release notes. You might get lucky in the crate repository or (much rarer) in a special module on docs.rs (for example, [like this](https://docs.rs/libloading/0.7.0/libloading/changelog/index.html)).

Answer (score 0):

There is no such feature.

The most standard practice is probably to have a `CHANGELOG.md` file at the root of a Git repository.
The Git repository link is available using the [`repository` key](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-repository-field). Both crates.io and docs.rs display these links.

For example, the `rand` crate does exactly this, and their CHANGELOG is available at https://github.com/rust-random/rand/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md